# Check value in one column to show info in another column

Tags: php, mysql

In the method of getting the product the user has paid to buy, there are two options: delivery and pick-up/infistall.

If delivery, then the user will write the address where the product will have to address.

If pickup/infistall, the user will choose the nearest place/stall to pick up the product.

All the information will posted on the input form.

Now I want to get the data to show in the page after the user has chosen the method of getting the product.

I create a new column in the table named as method.

I want to check in the table of method:

- If the row in the column method is delivery, then find the information in the row in the column delivery.
- And vice versa, If the row in the column method is infistall, then find the information in the row in the column infistall.

[image]

Comment: write a mysql_query in php to get the method first then based on methos get the additional column

Comment: @Choco `select method from table_name` then what next...

Answer (score 0):

Try sql like such in php (I suppose you can deal with sql query in PHP):

```
select Method,IF(Method='Infistall',Infistall,Delivery) as Detail from product_table
```

It would give result like that：

```
Method     | Detail
-----------|----------
Infistall  | Address_Infistall
Delivery   | Address_Delivery
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL CASE Syntax

```
SELECT 
(CASE method 
WHEN 'infistal' THEN infistall 
ELSE delivery END CASE) AS delevery_type 
FROM product_table
```

(note: not tested)